# Xcode intellisense meaning of letters in colored boxes like f,T,C,M,P,C,K,# etc

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4, intellisense

Recently, I have started using Xcode 4 for developing iOS apps.

In Xcode intellisense's autocomplete box, there are some letters in colored boxes before every suggestion. I know that they represent the **property of the word we are typing** like f,T,C,M,P,C,K,# etc. 
[image]

> Is there some kind of glossary available to find their quick meanings?

Meanings of f,C,T,# are understandable (function, class etc) but there are many others which I dont know. I assume these letters are standard across all IDEs like Visual Studio, Netbeans etc. Correct me if I am wrong.

Please suggest.

Comment: Xcode... the official apple's editor with 2.9 stars :)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

In Xcode this is called "Code Sense". And these icons also exist in Xcode 3. These icons are also used in symbol navigation.

**Red**: macros

- [image: #] = macro (think `#define`)

**Brown**: Core Data / namespace

- [image: C] = modeled **c**lass
- [image: M] = modeled **m**ethod
- [image: P] = modeled **p**roperty
- [image: N] = C++ **n**amespace

**Orange**: aliased types

- [image: C with underscore] = Objective-C **c**ategory
- [image: E] = **e**num
- [image: T] = **t**ypedef / **t**ypealias
- [image: Ex] = Swift **ex**tension

**Green**: variables

- [image: B] = **b**inding
- [image: f] = **f**unction
- [image: F] = **f**ield
- [image: K] = **c**onstant
- [image: L] = **l**ocal variable
- [image: O] = IB**O**utlet
- [image: V] = **v**ariable (can be ivar, global var, local var, etc.)
- [image: x] = parameter (think *f(x)*)

**Blue**: methods

- [image: A] = IB**A**ction
- [image: M] = **m**ethod
- [image: P] = **p**roperty

**Purple**: aggregate types

- [image: C] = **c**lass (Objective-C, Swift or C++)
- [image: CE] = **c**lass **e**xtension
- [image: Pr] = Objective-C/Swift **pr**otocol
- [image: S] = **s**truct
- [image: U] = **u**nion

**Gray**: snippets

- [image: {}] = snippets

**Icons**: `#pragma mark` or comments

- [image: Flag] = `!!!: ...`
- [image: Patch] = `FIXME: ...`
- [image: ?] = `???: ...`
- [image: Items] = `TODO: ...`
- [image: List] = `MARK: ...`

You should be able to look up the meanings from the filenames from `/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Resources/Xcode.SourceCodeSymbolKind.*.Icon.tiff`*.

In later versions of Xcode, the path is moved to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Resources/Assets.car`, see [Analysing Assets.car file in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630418/analysing-assets-car-file-in-ios) on how to extract the images from the *.car

Comment: Nice, but more nice if you could put the icons and the explanation together.

Comment: Can you explain what "modeled" means in the context of "modeled class/method/property"?

Comment: The icons are now stored in `/Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Assets.car`. You can extract the contents of this file using [`cartool`](https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/cartool).

Comment: Can we make any custom icons for something?

Comment: is the link has changed?

Comment: They seemed to have moved again in Xcode 13 beta. I haven't been able to find their new location. The closest I could find was `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTUserInterfaceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Assets.car`, but I don't see any of these icons using [AssetCatalogTinkerer](https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer)

Comment: `/Users/Alex/Desktop/plists/DVTSymbolIcons.dvticonspecsc` is a PLIST that defines a bunch of icons programmatically. I think they're using this to generate these symbols on-the-fly.

Comment: You should add blue `I` initializer to this list

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the meaning behind the "rM" icon. I finally found the answer (many thanks to kennytm):

The "rM" symbol represents a recursive method.

[image]

[image]