# Search result icons in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, icons

I'm looking for info on the icons displayed in search results in Xcode.

The meaning of some icons is obvious, I think.

M = Method, C = Class, S = Struct, Pr = Protocol, etc.  But others are not so obvious.

What do you call these icons in the Xcode help listing ?
Is there a "legend" that describes these icons ?

I've tried searching but I'm at a loss what to call these icons.

I can provide a pic if necessary, but can't post one.

possum

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode intellisense meaning of letters in colored boxes like f,T,C,M,P,C,K,# etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662395/xcode-intellisense-meaning-of-letters-in-colored-boxes-like-f-t-c-m-p-c-k-etc)

Answer (score 11):

Can't find any help about them either but with find-fu I think found them in `/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources` named `Xcode.SourceCodeSymbolKind.Category.Icon.pdf` etc.

**Update:** Did some Inkscape and HTML fiddling and generated this image:

[image: Source code kind image]

Comment: outstanding, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad you liked it :) Are you new to Stackoverflow? generally you should mark the answer as accepted instead of upvoting when marking a question as answered.

Comment: what is the new place of this icons ?

Comment: Sorry no idea. Maybe you can do some find and grepping?