# Xcode 4.5 IDE Symbol Icons

Tags: xcode

Can anyone tell me what the icons represent in Xcode 4.5's Find Panel or Symbol Navigator?

[image]

Some examples are:

- blue background containing 'M' (method maybe?)
- green containing
- 'x'
- purple containing 'C'
- green containing 'L'
- green containing 'V'
- purple containing 'Pr' (protocol i guess)

I have searched both in Xcode's Organiser Help and online to no avail. If there is a global list of all Xcode icons that would be even better!

Comment: What do you mean by the XCode "Find Panel"? I am a bit lost here. To post a screenshot, press Command+shift+4 which will give you a crosshair and drag a box over the place you are talking about to save it on Mac Desktop, then use the Upload command in your "edit" question section and post it there.

Comment: if i understand right. What you are talking about IS NOT the find panel. It is above the find panel. I believe that is a file navigation  panel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode intellisense meaning of letters in colored boxes like f,T,C,M,P,C,K,# etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662395/xcode-intellisense-meaning-of-letters-in-colored-boxes-like-f-t-c-m-p-c-k-etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I know.

- The M thing denotes the Method
- The C thing denotes the Class
- The P thing denotes a Property
- The O denotes a Outlet
- The V is a instance variable (unless it is known by another name)
- The C with underline, I think is a interface extension inside the .m file
- The Pr is a protocol

Never Saw a 'L' before.

Comment: OK, it is the Find Navigation panel specifically - i am new to XCode as you can tell. I cannot post any screenshots until i get 10 points. thanks.

Comment: Look at the edited answer. If it answer what you need, please mark as answer! Thank you!

Comment: This addresses most of the symbols so i'll mark it as 'answered'. Poor documentation from Apple.

Comment: I found a more complete answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705427/search-result-icons-in-xcode?rq=1