# Xcode symbol icons... definitive list?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Where can one find an exhaustive list of all of the global symbol **icons** used in Xcode? (i.e., for class, method, property, model, configuration, etc.) I have not seen them in the Xcode user guide, but perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.

**Examples:**

- blue "M" = method
- red "M" = model
- purple "C" = class
- green "C" = configuration
- blue "E" = entity
- blue "P" = property

***NOTE: I'm specifically trying to figure out what the red "O" is in a Core Data entity relationship (Instead of a red "M"), but figured it'd be nice to see them all clearly defined somewhere.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red “O” means it's a to-one relationship.  If you change it to a to-many relationship in the Data Model inspector, it changes to a red “M”.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, rob. Do you know where a complete list of these might be found?

Comment: I don't know.  Possibly nowhere but the Xcode source code.  The Xcode documentation hasn't even been updated for the new look of the model editor.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode -> Preferences -> Font & color, there's a list.

Comment: I can't find the list.  Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: @robmayoff, I think Evaristoyok is confused... That looks like source code style prefs only.

Comment: yes I'am :S Maybe this link could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662395/xcode-intellisense-meaning-of-letters-in-colored-boxes-like-f-t-c-m-p-c-k-etc