# Significance of the symbol used in support string in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, symbols

I am a bit confused about the symbols that I get when typing anything in Xcode that corresponds to a defined class,enum or anything else.Suppose when we type **UITableView** on Xcode then we get support string like this.

[image]

So the symbols which we are getting in the extreme left like **C** for Tableview and that I suppose to my understanding corresponds to a class.Similarly we get **V** I think for variable or **K** may be for enum.

I want to know what we call these symbols and is there any basic criteria that a symbol like **k** is defined for enum?Also what are the `significance of those symbols`?

There are also some conditions for which symbols are `not defined`.Like suppose we write **int** there is no symbol for int as we can see below.

[image]

There are also some symbols like **#** and **T** used in the above image.What are the significance of those.Please give me some brief idea about this topic and suggest me some tutorial if possible.Thanks.

Comment: # means that it is the result of a #define and T means it is a typdef. The symbols just help provide you some clues when selecting the right completion as to what the object is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the answer from a different question after a long time today.

Reference:- [What is that symbol before NSInteger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23647834/what-is-that-symbol-before-nsinteger)

Here is a more complete list of symbols, taken from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662395/xcode-intellisense-meaning-of-letters-in-colored-boxes-like-f-t-c-m-p-c-k-etc)** question.

#### Red: Macros

```
# = macro (think #define)
```

#### Brown: Core Data / Namespace

```
C = modeled class
M = modeled method
P = modeled property
N = C++ namespace
```

#### Orange: Aliased types

```
C̲ = Objective-C category
E = enum
T = typedef
```

#### Green: Variables

```
B = binding
ƒ = function
F = field
K = constant
L = local variable
O = IBOutlet
V = variable (can be ivar, global var, local var, etc.)
x = parameter (think f(x))
```

#### Blue: Methods

```
A = IBAction
M = method
P = property
```

#### Purple: Aggregate types

```
C = class (Objective-C or C++)
₠ = class extension
Pr = Objective-C protocol
S = struct
U = union
```

You should be able to look up the meanings from the filenames from `/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Resources/Xcode.SourceCodeSymbolKind.*.Icon.tiff.`

Note that, not all icons are used in Code Sense, as these are shared by all Xcode components.