# What is that symbol before NSInteger?

Tags: ios

when we type `NSInteger` in `Xcode`, then a symbol shows before it like: C, #, T etc.

So what is that symbol stands for?

I share a screenshot please anybody can guide me ?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the list:

```
T - typedef
C - Class
# - #define
V - Property
K - Constant
f - C Function
M - Objective C Method
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more complete list of symbols, taken from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662395/xcode-intellisense-meaning-of-letters-in-colored-boxes-like-f-t-c-m-p-c-k-etc)** question.

#### Red: Macros

```
# = macro (think #define)
```

#### Brown: Core Data / Namespace

```
C = modeled class
M = modeled method
P = modeled property
N = C++ namespace
```

#### Orange: Aliased types

```
C̲ = Objective-C category
E = enum
T = typedef
```

#### Green: Variables

```
B = binding
ƒ = function
F = field
K = constant
L = local variable
O = IBOutlet
V = variable (can be ivar, global var, local var, etc.)
x = parameter (think f(x))
```

#### Blue: Methods

```
A = IBAction
M = method
P = property
```

#### Purple: Aggregate types

```
C = class (Objective-C or C++)
₠ = class extension
Pr = Objective-C protocol
S = struct
U = union
```

Comment: If you think that the exact question has been answered before, you can leave a comment or flag as a duplicate. There is no need to post an *exact copy* of the answer to the identical question. - Btw. the path given at the end of your answer does not exist for current Xcode versions.

Comment: Updated the answer with regards to the path.
I will take care about this duplicate stuff from now on. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

1. `# - Macro define`
2. V - Property
3. M - Methods
4. K - Constants variable
5. f - Function
6. T - typedef enum
7. C - Class
8. {} - Instance Type Blocks