# Inference is showing two different variables with same name?

Tags: xcode, variables, swift-playground

[image]

//Im confused on what the 
'V's and 'L' stand for, which ones do I choose? This always happens and confuses me on which variabel I Should choose; they both have the same name but there's an 'L' and a 'V' for these 2 variables: speed and speedLimit???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode intellisense meaning of letters in colored boxes like f,T,C,M,P,C,K,# etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662395/xcode-intellisense-meaning-of-letters-in-colored-boxes-like-f-t-c-m-p-c-k-etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- L = Local Variable (the scope is restricted to the space betweeen the braces)
- V = Instance or Global Variable

For code completion it doesn't matter whether you choose V or L, the compiler will do the right thing.

Comment: ahh I see, you completely cleared the confusion......I was actually choosing whichever variable because they both had the same name and type......that probably mixed up my code where I needed to put a local, I probably put a global and vise versa , maybe I should go and rewrite those? @vadian

Comment: Rewriting is not necessary, it's even recommended to use the same name for instance variable and parameter name.